# Making a origami creation on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work

Would it be a violation of one of the thirty-nine [melachos](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610) if someone made a paper airplane or made origami creation on shabbos? (And I know a melacha is loosely translated as "creative work".)

Answer (score 8):

http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/203/Q2/

> Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Aurbach, zatzal, prohibits making toys - like a
>   boat, or hat - by folding paper, since it is like making a utensil.
>   However, if the paper was folded into a toy before Shabbat, it is
>   permitted to use it on Shabbat.
>
> Sources:
>
> Shemirat Shabbat Kehilchata Ch.16:19